# Integrating webpages and turbogears application

Tags: pylons, turbogears2, genshi

I am working on a Turbo Gears 2 application. The application directs a user through a set of questions. I like the templating system of TG2 (which of course is the idea) so I want to integrate the static web pages with TG2 also. This will allow me to abstract away the headers, sidebars, navbars and footers.

Please note that I am not talking about placing my 'static' files in the public directory of the application. I created a Controller called `WebController` and I am serving files through that. Of course the instance name of the controller is `web` so all my pages are accessible at the URL `http://mysite/web/page1.html` (for example)

Now the question - is it possible to have all pages at the root level be redirected to `/web`. That way I can eliminate the `/web` in URLs for HTML pages.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I realize that my question was somewhat vague. After doing some research on my own, I found out that TurboGears does not use routes by default but uses CherryPy dispatching scheme. http://nxsy.org/unscientific-and-biased-comparison-of-django-pylons-and-turbogears was very helpful in understanding some of the high level architecture of TG.

I rely a lot on stackoverflow to solve my problems as I make progress in my application - so, here is hoping someone else can benefit by reading that discussion.